# amqp-coffee channels not closing

Tags: node.js, amqp

I have a problem with channels not closing in amqp-coffee. When using node-amqp I had the same issue, but resolved it with this queue option:

```
closeChannelOnUnsubscribe: true
```

Then when my socket.io client disconnected I would unsubscribe his consumerTag from the queue, and the channel would close:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    if (consumerTag) {
        my_queue.unsubscribe(consumerTag);
    }
});
```

Would there be an equivalent in amqp-coffee?

I'm trying all sorts of things like queue.channel.close(), consumer.cancel() and queue.delete(), but none seem to close the channels. I can see that they remain in rabbitmq dashboard with no consumer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newest version of amqp-coffee now supports the following:

`consumer.close();`

One point of confusion for me was where to get the consumer object. It is returned from the connection.consume call:

`var consumer = connection.consume(/* ... */);`